# SSRS Report Rendering Related

Tags: reporting-services

I have created SSRS Report using pivot and using matrix because in report we are using dynamic column display and sorting and It has 2 millions records. Report executed 2 min but rendering time take 10 minute. Please suggest approach for fast rendering.

Comment: Other than throwing a lot of money at hardware there is probably not much you can do. However, I can't visualise a report with 2 million that any user would actually want to read. Perhaps you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: 2 million data because using pivot. When report generated then only 25000 data.

Comment: I would suggest doing some of the aggregation in your dataset query rather than in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any function-related formatting (IIF(Fields!SomeField.Value>0, "white","red")) because SSRS will need to inspect every line. In fact, remove any SSRS functions you can and make SQL do the heavy lifting. I agree with @Alan that the report is still too big to be useful: ask the users what question they're trying to answer with that large of a data set and see if you can come up with a better way of answering it.

A better option for this type of analysis is Excel PowerPivot: let excel import the raw data and do the pivoting.